# Issue in connecting Apache Phoenix with node.js using npm jdbc package

Tags: node.js, jdbc, npm, apache-phoenix

I am using node.js v6 LTS and the npm [jdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) package to connect to  Apache phoenix on hortonworks.
My code is as below:-

```
var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');

var jar1='/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/public/drivers/phoenix-core-4.7.0.2.5.6.0-40.jar';
var jar2='/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/public/drivers/phoenix-queryserver-client-4.7.0.2.5.6.0-40.jar';
var jar3='/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/public/drivers/hbase-client-1.1.2.2.5.6.0-40.jar';

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  // Add all java options required by your project here.  You get one 
  //chance to setup the options before the first java call.
        jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  // Add all jar files required by your project here.  You get one chance to
  // setup the classpath before the first java call.
        jinst.setupClasspath([jar1,jar2,jar3]); // adding jars
    }

var config = {
    url:'jdbc:phoenix:ZK1,ZK2,ZK3:2181:/hbase-unsecure',
    drivername: 'org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver'
};

var phoenixHbase = new JDBC(config);
phoenixHbase.initialize(function(err) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected to Apache phoenix ...");
    }
});
```

But I am getting following errors:-

```
  { Error: Could not find class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more

    at Error (native)
    at JDBC.Pool.initialize (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/jdbc/lib/pool.js:135:10)
    at /home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/routes/app.js:71:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/ashish/seed-project-phoenix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10) cause: nodeJava_java_lang_NoClassDefFoundError {} }
{ Error: Error running static method
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:ZK1,ZK2,ZK3:2181:/hbase-unsecure
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at Error (native) cause: nodeJava_java_sql_SQLException {} }
```

There should be no problem with the connection string according to me and all the jar files have been added in accordance with the version.

Phoenix version:- 4.7.0.2.5.6.0-40
Hbase version :- 1.1.2.2.5.6.0-40

If anybody has done anything similar, please give some direction.

Comment: You need to add commons-logging to the classpath.

Comment: Also, you don't want to use the queryserverclient, you want the thick client.  I think you have the wrong JAR for Phoenix

Comment: @PaulBastide according to link below, there is no thick client jar for phoenix version. Is there any way I can resolve this issue  https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85323/how-can-be-found-phoenix-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-rep.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have added the org-apache-commons-logging.jar, but still I am getting errors :-  { Error: Could not find class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.apache.phoenix.util.ReadOnlyProps.<clinit>(ReadOnlyProps.java:46)
 at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) the error is too long to paste here ... this is the initials of the error

Comment: You will also need to add the SLF4J-api (and maybe other dependencies). A hint: maybe you should update your question instead of using comments to convey this information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sure Mark... will keep that in mind...